# Python ANTLR4 extraneous input plus tokens removal

Tags: antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree, context-free-grammar

I am trying to parse a text file and I want to create a grammar to catch specific text blocks let's say

a) the word 'specificWordA' or 'specWordB' followed by zero or more digits, or

b) the word 'testC' followed by 1 or more digits.

My grammar looks like this:

```
grammar Hello;

catchExpr : expr+ EOF;

expr : matchAB | matchC;

matchAB : TEXTAB DIGIT*;
matchC : TEXTC DIGIT+;

TEXTAB : ('specificWordA' | 'specWordB') ;
TEXTC : ('testC') ;
DIGIT : NUMBER+ ;
CHARS : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+ ;
SPACES : [ \r\t\n] ->skip;

fragment NUMBER: '0'..'9'+ ;
```

I am using ANTLR4 and I have compiled the code both on JAVA (to use the TestRig gui command for the AST) and Python2 (to provide a custom listener to traverse the tree). My file contains the following text:

```
specificWordA 11

specWordB specWordB specWordB testC 22 not not testD 
testD 11


testC teeeeeeeeeest
testD 2

end here
```

Please could someone help my with the following questions:

1) Does ANTLR4 create nodes by default for every token I have defined in my grammar? How can I remove them so as to get a simplified version of the AST (see image below there are nodes for every sequence of characters that match token CHARS)?

[image]

2) Why does "testC teeeeeeeeeest testD 2 end here"
matches an expression? My rule is a text block 'testC' followed by at least one digit!

3) When I run my code I get the following messages:

```
line 3:39 extraneous input 'not' expecting {<EOF>, TEXTAB, 'testC'}
line 7:6 mismatched input 'teeeeeeeeeest' expecting {<EOF>, TEXTAB, 'testC'}
```

What does extraneous input mean? Do I have to change my grammar or it is just a warning?
Based on these questions,

[ANTLR4 extraneous input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828572/antlr4-extraneous-input)

[ANTLR4: Extraneous Input error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371310/antlr4-extraneous-input-error)

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my grammar!